# rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following tables:

create table files (
id int auto_increment primary_key
name varchar(255)
)

create table users (
id int auto_increment primary_key
name varchar(255)
)

create table admins (
file_id int
user_id int
)

I would like to be able to say get the user names of the file admin. How do I create an association to get this one

If I do has_many :admins on the files, then I can do file.admins to get the ids and to get the user names of those admins I would have to sub queries using the Find. I would like to avoid that one

Answer (score 0):

For Rails questions, rather than sharing your database create-table syntax, you should share your database migrations (just open up schema.rb and copy/paste).

It looks like you just have users, some of whom have admin privileges. The easier way of doing this is to just have a `t.boolean :admin, :default => false` column on your user model.

A nice benefit of this approach is that Active Record will provide you with a `User#admin?` method that is highly readable in conditionals and such (i.e. `<%= render 'admin_menu' if @user.admin? %>`).

This also sidesteps your concerns about additional queries to get the usernames after getting the listed admins.

```
# app/models/file.rb
class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

@files = File.where(:something => true).include(:user)
@files.map(&:name) #=> ['Bob', 'Cindy', ...]
```

Comment: Actually, adding an admin flag on the user table does not work for me. I have many files and each file can have different admins. That's why I have an admin table that links the file_id with user_id.